# Can't continue a program when binance api(connection) error occured

Tags: python, api, binance

I'm fetching OHLCV data from Binance via Binance api on AWS-EC2.
But sometime(once a couple of days) error "104, 'ECONNRESET'" occur and program stop.

The program written in Python3.7.3 and run on AWS-EC2

The code is following. But this code couldn't continue.

I want to continue the program running when any api or connection error occured.

How should I handle this error ?

```
while True:

    ..............

    try :
        klines = client.get_historical_klines(ticker_symbol, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, _from_str, _until_str)

    except BinanceAPIException as e:
        print(e)
        print('Something went wrong. Error occured at %s. Wait for 1 hour.' % (datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(timezone('UTC'))))
        sleep(3600)
        continue

    ..............
```

All error massege are following.

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File
>   "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 600, in urlopen
>       chunked=chunked)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 384, in _make_request
>       six.raise_from(e, None)   File "", line 2, in raise_from   File
>   "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 380, in _make_request
>       httplib_response = conn.getresponse()   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 1321, in getresponse
>       response.begin()   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 296, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 257, in _read_status
>       line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line
>   589, in readinto
>       return self._sock.recv_into(b)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py",
>   line 312, in recv_into
>       return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py",
>   line 302, in recv_into
>       raise SocketError(str(e)) OSError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 449, in send
>       timeout=timeout   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 638, in urlopen
>       _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py",
>   line 368, in increment
>       raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py",
>   line 685, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 600, in urlopen
>       chunked=chunked)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 384, in _make_request
>       six.raise_from(e, None)   File "", line 2, in raise_from   File
>   "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 380, in _make_request
>       httplib_response = conn.getresponse()   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 1321, in getresponse
>       response.begin()   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 296, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py",
>   line 257, in _read_status
>       line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line
>   589, in readinto
>       return self._sock.recv_into(b)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py",
>   line 312, in recv_into
>       return self.recv_into(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py",
>   line 302, in recv_into
>       raise SocketError(str(e)) urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "BTC_USDT_BINANCE_minutes.py", line 54, in 
>       klines = client.get_historical_klines(ticker_symbol, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, _from_str, _until_str)   File
>   "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/binance/client.py",
>   line 765, in get_historical_klines
>       first_valid_ts = self._get_earliest_valid_timestamp(symbol, interval)   File
>   "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/binance/client.py",
>   line 723, in _get_earliest_valid_timestamp
>       endTime=None   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/binance/client.py",
>   line 705, in get_klines
>       return self._get('klines', data=params)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/binance/client.py",
>   line 207, in _get
>       return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/binance/client.py",
>   line 181, in _request_api
>       return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/binance/client.py",
>   line 175, in _request
>       response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 546, in get
>       return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 533, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
>   line 646, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 498, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
>   OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')"))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [`python-binance`](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io) module, most likely the error happens because you are trying to reuse the `client` after long time (server timeout). You can try to recreate the `client` first:

```
...
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
while True:
    ...
    try :
        klines = client.get_historical_klines(ticker_symbol, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, _from_str, _until_str)

    except BinanceAPIException as e:
        print(e)
        print('Something went wrong. Error occured at %s. Wait for 1 hour.' % (datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(timezone('UTC'))))
        sleep(3600)
        client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
        continue
...
```

The reason is because the `[Client][2]` uses `requests` [Session](http://2.python-requests.org/projects/3/user/advanced/?highlight=session) underneath which imply usage of `urllib3`'s connection pooling. This connection pooling can not be reused after timeout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I modified my code as suggested by you.
And the program have run about 5days !

But in the first place, I saw error output, the print code "print(e)" & "print('Something went wrong. ....." were not outputted.

I don't have any confidence that the program can handle the exception correctly.

Please let me know if you have any further ideas.

Comment: How about trying to simulate the exception by running it in your local machine then disconnect-reconnect the internet connection?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try it.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution @Yohanes Gultom, may I know you if your approach would also work for the following errors: `RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response`, `ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`, `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))` ?

Comment: I have no knowledge about that specific error. But I guess it should work for any temporary network issue